# German translation of "quantale"

Tags: order-theory, lattice-orders, translation-request, mathematical-german

A [quantale](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quantale) is a monoidal sup-lattice. Is there a German translation for that term?

I was guessing it is just "Quantal", but I find only two results ([here](https://core.ac.uk/download/pdf/250263484.pdf) and [here](https://www.informatik.uni-augsburg.de/lehrstuehle/dbis/pmi/lectures/vorhergehende_semester/ss08/algsem/script/text/kap21_text.pdf), the second even has a different meaning). This is why I was wondering if there is actually a different translation which is more commonly used.